# Saving, getting and setting length of a cube (extending classes)

Tags: java, oop

I already wrote a class *Geom* that represents three-dimensional, geometrical forms and works with the attributes `double dx, dy, dz` (the coordinates of the form) and `String colour` (the colour of the form). Now I am supposed to get more specific, and I want to write a class *Cube* that extends *Geom* and that works furthermore with the attribute *edge length*, in order to calculate things like the volume or area of the form.

In order to do so, I need to write a method `private double length`, which *saves* the length of the edges. Besides that, I need to implement *get-* and *set-methods*.

This should be quite easy actually, but I don't what I have to do here. I started like this:

```
public class Cube extends Geom {

  int edge;

  public Cube (double dx, double dy, double dz, String colour, double edge) {

  super(dx, dy, dz, colour);
  edge = ///I don't know what do to here

  }

  private double length(double edge) {
  this.edge = edge;
  return this.edge;

  }

  public double getEdge() {
  double a = length();
  return a;
  }

  public void setEdge() {
  this.edge = edge
  }

  ...
```

This doesn't seem to make much sense though. I receive two errors, one telling me that `this.edge = edge` is a lossy conversion from double to int and one telling me that `double a = width();` isn't possible because the method `width()` cannot be applied to the given types. I don't quite see the sense of "saving" the length first, then getting it and setting it in the end.

Comment: You have declared `int edge` but the parameter to `length` is a `double`.

Comment: That's indeed the first mistake here, thanks!

Comment: If you could show the base class, it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Cube extends Geom {
```

first of all should encapsulate variables like this and create getter and setter for them.

```
private int edge;

public Cube (double dx, double dy, double dz, String colour, int edge) {

super(dx, dy, dz, colour);
```

if you want to be able construct the Geom object with a given edge
you need something like, and change the parameter type to int

```
this.edge=edge;
```

this will set the given parameter to your variable 'this' keyword means that you want to invoke to this class edge variable, as the parameter name is the same.

I don't know why you created method length here what it should return ??
As far as i can see it returns the edge, then its the getter job to do so.

```
  }

  private double length(double edge) {
  this.edge = edge;
  return this.edge;

  }
```

You expect to return double while your edge variable is an int, probably want this.

```
  public int getEdge() {
  return edge;
```

or

```
  return this.edge;
```

it doest matter on that point

```
  }
```

and the setter should take a value that matches the variable
again you dont necessarily need to say this.edge as the compiler will know what to do as this is the only edge variable here.

```
  public void setEdge(int value) {
  this.edge = value;
  }
```

then you can do your calculations and stuff in the length method and parse it to double if you need to, or if need double in the first place, just change the type of the edge to double

Comment: Thank you very much! I implemeted it like this and tested it. It works. :-) But what kind of role does the value-variable play here? Where does the parameter come from?

Comment: value is for your setter, is an API that you or someone else will use to set the value of edge. he will use geom.setEdge(23); lets say to set it on geom object that been constructed.

Comment: value parameter in this case is something that you demand - imagine how would you set the edge if you would not be able to say how much you want it to be to ?

Comment: Oh, okay! But it's not the same parameter that I give in my test-class, is it? Because in my test-class, I constructed an object like this: `Cube Cube1 = new Cube(1.0, 2.5, 3.1, "White", 2.0);`

Comment: ... where `2.0` denotes the length of the edges.

Comment: But it has 5 paramteres. The 4 paramteres dx, dy, dz and colour were already introduced in the Geom class, only the length of the edges is new here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132418/discussion-between-krystian-k-and-julian).